# Is there a DRY rule regarding decorators?

Tags: python, python-decorators, dry, class-method

I was under the impression that if you use two or more of the same kind of decorator methods ***in a row*** such as @classmethod in a class, you don't have to use @classmethod twice (DRY principle).

For example, if you use @classmethod and the next method defined in the class also has cls as the first implicit argument, then Python's interpreter should know that the second method is also a class method.

```
class Cat:
    holiness = 100
    luck = 100
    
    @classmethod
    def more_holiness(cls):
        cls.holiness += 1

    def more_luck(cls):
        cls.luck += 1

Cat.more_holiness() # Works fine.
Cat.more_luck() # Error outputted. Expected one argument.
```

How would I write this code without having to use @classmethod twice?

Expected both methods to be class methods, got an unexpected result.

Comment: Dunno where you got this idea, but Python doesn't do anything like that. The inference rule you suggest would lead to far, far too many errors with decorators that aren't specifically `@classmethod`.

Comment: What's wrong with writing `@classmethod` again? It's just one extra line, and it's more explicit. Do you have a lot more classmethods in your real code?

Comment: @wjandrea I just expected because I'm using cls as the implicit first argument, Python should infer this is a class method as well. tbh, I don't know why it shouldn't work like this.

Comment: You could name the first argument to your method `stoney_baloney` and Python would not care either way. If you pass it through the `@classmethod` decorator, a call from an instance will still bind to the class (just as if you called it from the class itself); if you don't decorate it, it will bind to the instance it is called from (or not at all if called from the class). The name has nothing to do with anything. It is just convention.

Comment: "Decorating" a function declaration `f` with decorator `@dec` means calling and assigning `f = dec(f)` in the surrounding namespace. Nothing more and nothing less. Why should that call to `dec` and the re-assignment be repeated, just because the following function declaration `g` happens to name its first argument the same as `f`? Seems like very arbitrary behavior that just invites errors.

Answer (score 2):

A decorator can only decorate one function or class at a time. For your purpose, you can create a class decorator instead to decorate all non-dunder methods with `classmethod`:

```
def classmethods(cls):
    for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
        if callable(obj) and not name.startswith('__'):
            setattr(cls, name, classmethod(obj))
    return cls
```

so that:

```
@classmethods
class Cat:
    holiness = 100
    luck = 100

    def more_holiness(cls):
        cls.holiness += 1

    def more_luck(cls):
        cls.luck += 1

Cat.more_holiness()
Cat.more_luck()
print(Cat.holiness)
print(Cat.luck)
```

Outputs:

```
101
101
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ImmaculateThisMicrokernel

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer and the comments have already pointed out, decorators in Python don't work that way. Decorators are simple function calls that act on the following declaration (either a class or a function declaration). They are not a form of state that affects future declarations in the same scope.

More broadly, you're misunderstanding the DRY principle. DRY, short for "don't repeat yourself", is paraphrased thusly according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

> Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system

It says nothing about repeating individual lines of code. A single `@classmethod` declaration being repeated is not a violation of DRY. Indeed, several three-line functions that do similar computations is not a violation of DRY; I often see (and write) code that behaves that way. Sometimes it makes sense to add an abstraction layer, and sometimes it doesn't.

The DRY principle is about data, not lines of code. If my program is modelling properties of a spacecraft, then, for example, there should be one class somewhere that encapsulates the craft's target interior temperature. If I have four different classes that are all simultaneously trying to monitor the temperature, then *that* is a violation of DRY, since none of those classes can reasonably say that they're the "authoritative" representation of that information.